# Very strange javascript issue with booleans

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

Booleans will work before setting variables inside a function but not after? The variables are all taken from forms except "status".

Here is the function:

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script>
function signup(){

//    if(1==1){                     -----When I place this here, the alert comes up.
//           alert("yes");
//    }
var u = _("username").value;
var e = _("email").value;
var p1 = _("pass1").value;
var p2 = _("pass2").value;
var c = _("country").value;
var g = _("gender").value;
var a = _("age").value;
var o = _("occ").value;
var status = _("status");

// Nothing below here works

if(u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || g == "" || a == "" || o == ""){
status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
     alert("true");
} else if(p1 != p2){
    status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";

}

 else if( _("terms").style.display == "none"){
    status.innerHTML = "Please view the terms of use";
} else {
    _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
    status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signupfront.php");
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
       if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){
                status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
                _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+u+", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
 }
   }
    }
    ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&g="+g+"&a="+a+"&o="+o);
}
}
```

This function is called by a button, and I want the function to return the messages alongside the button.

```
<button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>
<span id="status"></span>
```

main.js contains the following:

```
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I have been looking at it for hours and cannot figure it out.
Thanks in advance

Here is the html as requested:

```
<body>

<div id="pageMiddle">
  <h3>Create Account</h3>
  <form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>Username: </div>
    <input id="username" type="text" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16">
    <span id="unamestatus"></span>
    <div>Email Address:</div>
    <input id="email" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">
    <div>Create Password:</div>
    <input id="pass1" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Confirm Password:</div>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Age:</div>
    <input id="age" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="3">
    <div>Occupation:</div>
    <input id="occ" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="88">
    <div>Gender:</div>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m">Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="f">Female
    <div>Country:</div>
    <select id="country" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    //long list of countries here
    </select>
    <div>
      <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="openTerms()">
        View the Terms Of Use
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="terms" style="display:none;">
      <h3>Our Terms Of Use</h3>
      <p>v</p>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>
    <span id="status"></span>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It kinda sounds like it there's a JavaScript error before it gets to the second set of statements. Are you sure there aren't any errors in the console?

Comment: How would I go about checking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `gender` input

```
<div>Gender:</div>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="m">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="f">Female
```

Here's your mistake

```
var g = _("gender").value;
```

The code breaks at the above line because you're trying to get the value of an element with id equals `gender`, but there's no element with `id="gender"` attribute.

You need to change the gender input to the following, where the radio buttons have the unique id (`genderMale` and `genderFemale`)

```
<div>Gender:</div>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderMale" value="m">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderFemale" value="f">Female
```

then use the following syntax to assign the value of the selected gender to `g` variable

```
var g = "";
if (document.getElementById("genderMale").checked) {
    g = _("genderMale").value;
} else if (document.getElementById("genderFemale").checked) {
    g = _("genderFemale").value;
}
```

Below is the modified part of the javascript

```
var u = _("username").value;
var e = _("email").value;
var p1 = _("pass1").value;
var p2 = _("pass2").value;
var c = _("country").value;
var a = _("age").value;
var o = _("occ").value;
var status = _("status");
var g = "";
if (document.getElementById("genderMale").checked) {
    g = _("genderMale").value;
} else if (document.getElementById("genderFemale").checked) {
    g = _("genderFemale").value;
}

if (u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || g == "" || a == "" 
    || o == "") {
    status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    alert("true");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zpeu4fq9/1/

Answer (score 1):

if any of your `input` fields that you are referencing in the variable declaration do not exist your code will fail, because you are calling `.value` on an undefined field.

post your **HTML** and we can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
if(1===1){                     
     alert("yes");
}

if(u === "" || e === "" || p1 === "" || p2 === "" || c === "" || g === "" || a === "" || o === ""){
  status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
  alert("true");
} else if(p1 != p2){
  status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";

}
```

Hope this help